# Counting the times a string value has occured by group

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am working on a function in R that will help to identify user sessions from our website data. A session is determined by when a user logs in, what they do while logged in, and logs out. We currently have a giant list of all the user log ins, actions, and log outs. The function I am working to create will loop through the actions taken by each user and detect for a log in. Every time there is a log in the session count will be upped by 1 for that user.

Sudo code of what I am looking to accomplish:

```
Group by userid
Set i = 0
Begin Looping Through Action Types
    If type = ‘Log In’
        i = i+1
        return i 
    else
        return i
```

My current R code is as follows:

```
Table %>% group_by(userid) %>% mutate( Session_List = 
for (type in PinnacleActivityLog){
  i = 0
    if (str_detect(type, "Log In")){
      i = i+1
      Session_List = i
    }else{
      Session_List = i
    }                                                    
})
```

Data:

```
table <- data.frame(
  userid = c("111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "222", "222", "222", "111", "111", "222", "222", "222"),
  timestamp = c("11/2/2020 15:26", "11/2/2020 15:56", "11/2/2020 15:56", "11/2/2020 16:30", "11/2/2020 17:43", "11/2/2020 19:05", "11/4/2020 19:15", "11/4/2020 20:05", "11/3/2020 19:23", "11/3/2020 19:50", "11/3/2020 20:15", "11/4/2020 22:25", "11/4/2020 22:45", "11/5/2020 12:45", "11/5/2020 12:50", "11/5/2020 12:55"),
  type = c("Log In", "Search", "Click", "Click", "Search", "Log Out", "Log In", "Log Out", "Log In", "Search", "Log Out", "Log In", "Log Out", "Log In", "Click", "Log Out")
)
```

Desired Result

[image: End Objective]

Any assistance with how to adjust the R code to perform the task would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
table %>% 
  group_by(userid) %>% 
  mutate( Session_List = cumsum(str_detect(type, "Log In")))
```

The `str_detect` will be TRUE each time "Log In" is detected, and by using `cumsum` (the cumulative sum), you are basically incrementing the count by 1 each time that happens (because TRUE is treated as 1 and FALSE as 0 when summing up values)